# sizeof returns different values for the same struct

Tags: c, gcc, sizeof

I have two applications written in C that include the same header. In this header I have the declaration of a struct. I use the GCC compiler to compile both applications.

When I execute both applications, they produce different values of `sizeof(struct-defined-in-the-header)`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: There are a couple of possible reasons, without any more information about the differences between those two applications you will get only some wild guesses or some very general advice.

Comment: And this is why you can never make assumptions about the size of a struct.

Comment: @Kevin: This is slightly exaggerated. We can certainly assume the size of `struct { char x, y; }` is not less than 2.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, make sure to do a clean build of everything.

If the problem persists, this could mean that different compilation options have been used for the two translation units. I would capture the `gcc` command lines used for the two compilations, and would compare them, paying particular attention to any options having to do with alignment, structure padding etc.

Another possibility is that the definition of the struct depends on some preprocessor symbols, and the symbols get defined differently for the two translation units. Using `gcc -E` and comparing the struct definition in the two preprocessor outputs would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it wasn't gcc and it was single application, but there were different results of sizeof(MyStruct) in different .c files.
The reason was in different packing values for structures, because those .c files had included different sets of .h files before including header with declaration of MyStruct.
The solution I adopted was to create general header with setting appropriate packing value and including it into all my .h files after system and library headers, but before my headers.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is **not** a function. It is a compile-time operator.

You don't tell what header is giving you trouble.

A possible guess might be that some obscure preprocessor trick is removing some field in it, or changing the real type of the field. For example, imagine that one header `foo.h` has

```
// in file foo.h 
#ifdef FOO_BAR
typedef short number_t;
#else
typedef long number_t;
#endif
```

and another header `bar.h` has

```
// in file bar.h
#define FOO_BAR
#include "foo.h"
struct barbare_st {
   number_t num;
   char name[20];
};
```

To find out, you could use the `ptype` command of the `gdb` debugger, or simply look into the preprocessed form `xxx.i` of some file `xxx.c` obtained with

```
gcc -C -E -Dappropriate_defines -Iinclude_dirs/ xxx.c > xxx.i
```

Answer (score 0):

As Doc Brown commented, there are several possibilities. You should show the code. Here's another guess, though.

Maybe another variable is shadowing your `struct` in one of the cases? Like in:

```
extern struct { char foo; } bar;

void baz(void) {
    long bar;
    sizeof bar;  /* will be sizeof(long) */
}

void qux(short bar) {
    sizeof bar;  /* will be sizeof(short) */
}
```